# svn: remove file with @ in the filename

Tags: svn

I have a few systemd services including an instanced service unit under version control:

```
$ ls 
ios1.service
ios2.service
ios@.service
```

I'd like to remove it from the repository.  Normally this should be easy:

```
$ svn rm ios@.service
svn: E200009: 'ios@.service': a peg revision is not allowed here
```

How do I get around the peg syntax?

I tried renaming `ios{1,2}.service` temporarily and then using wildcards, but SVN doesn't seem to support wildcards.

```
$ svn mv ios1.service{,.bak}
$ svn mv ios2.service{,.bak}
$ svn rm 'ios*.service'
svn: E200005: Use --force to override this restriction (local modifications may be lost)
svn: E200005: 'ios*.service' is not under version control
```